# Get indefinite number of repeated matches within match?

Tags: python, regex

**XML that I'm trying to parse:**

```
<target>
    <mrk mtype="seg" mid="1">Text 1</mrk>
    <mrk mtype="seg" mid="2">Text 2</mrk>
</target>
```

**What I want to do, more specifically:**

Use regex to find and replace the text within the mrk.../mrk tags, but ONLY for mrk tags that are within target tags (ignoring mrk tags that are within source tags, for example).

**What I have tried:**

```
<target>(<mrk mtype=\"seg\" mid=\"\d\">(.*?)</mrk>)</target>
```

**Failure:**

This lumps Text1 and Text2 together.

I want to get them separately, regardless of whether there is only one set of mrk tags within the target tag, or there are 2, 3, etc...

***Is this possible to do with regex?***

Another way of explaining what I what to do would be to say that I want to capture:

```
<target>(.*?)</target>
```

and then capture all instances of:

```
<mrk mtype=\"seg\" mid=\"\d\">(.*?)</mrk>
```

individually within the target tags -- not lumped together like they are now.

**Other failure:**

As far as I can tell, I can't break this down into two expressions, as what I need to do is first find target tags and then replace the text between the marked tags within the target tags.

Comment: why are you parsing xml as text? why not load it as xml and parse the content? [here](https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-xml-files-in-python/) is an example of working with xml

Comment: So individual tag contents remain isolated in new lines?

Answer (score 0):

`"(.[^"]*)"` with the global flag would give you anything within quotes individually

Comment: What question are you answering?

Comment: The question was edited, originally it said they were looking to replace the tags contained within quotes

Comment: I don't see such question in the revision history.

Comment: @AleksW Actually, for some reason stackoverflow hides any text within <>'s, so that's why it looked like it originally said '' tags instead of '<target>' tags, etc.